# Convert int array to std::vector<int*>

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to "convert" an integer C style array to `std::vector<int*>` without using a `for` loop, or rather insert pointers of all array items in a vector.

I'm currently implementing this by doing the follow:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    vector.push_back(&values[i]);
}
```

Is it possible to implement this by using `std::vector::insert()` and `std::being/end`?

Comment: It might be a bit easier if you could use `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>` instead.

Comment: Wait, do you want to convert the array into a vector - i.e. have `int` elements - or have a vector of pointers into the array, i.e. `int*` elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is a useful algorithm in [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) for copying values between containers that aren't implicitly compatible but for which you can provide a transformation function.

Here is an example of how you could populate a `std::vector<int*>` from a `std::array<int, N>`

```
int values[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
std::vector<int*> v1;

std::transform(
    std::begin(values), std::end(values),   // Copy from
    std::back_inserter(v1),                 // Copy to
    [](auto& i) {                           // Transformation function
        return &i;
    });
```

Edit : Changed `std::array<int, 5>` to `int[5]` to account for edits in the question.

Comment: `[](int& i)` C++11 compatible (and shorter`:)`

Comment: Should i reserve( v1.reserve(5); ) space for v1 before calling std::transform to get rid of reallocations, or is std::transform smart enough?

Comment: @grimgrom `std::transform` doesn't know that you are assigning to a vector so it can't `reserve`. All it sees is an output iterator-like object (`std::back_inserter`). And that object doesn't know how many elements it is about to insert into `v1`. So nobody has enough information to `reserve` for you. If you want to avoid reallocation overhead, you need to `reserve` yourself.

Comment: This is a good answer. IMO, OP's asking for how to map one sequence to another and C++ equivalent to higher-order function map is `std::transform`, https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/higher-order-functions, so this perfectly fits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is rather fancy way to do what you want, but it is generic and it doesn't use *for* loop - it just passes pointers of array's elements to vector constructor:

```
template<class T, size_t ... Ints, size_t N>
std::vector<T*> makePtrsHelper(std::array<T,N>& arr, std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
       return std::vector<T*>{ & std::get<Ints>(arr)... }; 
       // vector ctor taking pointers to array's elements
}

template<class T, size_t N>
std::vector<T*> makePtrs(std::array<T,N>& array) {
    return makePtrsHelper(array, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main(){
    std::array<int,5> ar{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int*> v = makePtrs(ar);
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y5oeVK)

Answer (score -2):

**Note**: as pointed out in comments my below answer is wrongly related to `vector<int>` not `vector<int*>` which was asked for in question.

---

Solution with `std::copy` and C-style array:

```
int ar[] = {1,2,3,4,3,2,1};
std::vector<int> vec;
std::copy(ar, ar+sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]), back_inserter(vec));
```

Comment: `vec` is an `std::vector<int>`. The question is asking for an `std::vector<int*>`

Comment: `ar, ar+sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0])` should be `std::begin(ar), std::end(ar)`.

Comment: If you need to `std::copy` to a `std::back_inserter(v)` you should probably do `v.insert` instead. It will allocate only once.